# Creating and populating tables dynamically

Tags: asp.net

Hello I'm developing a asp.  Net page where I want to populate many tables in the ui
But I want it to be dynamic. 
Eg: If I retrieve only 2 rows as per search criteria then I want to display only 2 tables.
I tried dynamic table creation using string builder but I got a null reference because the table Id was not being read . Is there any other way where I can create tables dynamically in the html page or should I do it in the code behind itself , then get the Id using flow control and then populate the table. Please help!!!

The problem of creatig tables dynamically has been rectified but now i cannot retrive their ids so that i can print values retrived from the datatbase in it using id.text command.
this is my code

```
StringBuilder htmlTable = new StringBuilder();
htmlTable.AppendLine("<table>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("<tr>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("<th>colum1</th>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("<th>colum2</th>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("<th>colum3</th>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("</tr>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("<tr>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("<td><asp:Label runat='server' id='lblt0'></asp:Label></td>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("<td>colum2data</td>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("<td>colum3data</td>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("</tr>");
htmlTable.AppendLine("</table>");
litTable.Text = htmlTable.ToString();

//litTable is the id of my asp:literal tag
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Gridview`?  Also, post some of your code from your dynamic table creation.  Maybe it can be salvaged.

Comment: hello this is a piece of code but the problen now is thet i have created tables dynamically but i need to retrive their ids so that i can use id.text Command to print values retrieved from database into it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a table with a `runat=server` tag in this manner.  Adding items to a literal control can only create client side markup not server side controls.

Your best route is to use a GridView as suggested or an HtmlTable

GridView: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

HtmlTable: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If your example really is as trivial as the one you provided an HtmlTable might be the easiest route.  Though if you want to populate your table from a database or some other data source a GridView is your best option.